# url rewrite 404 - Not found

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i tried this to rewrite url,and worked perfectly

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule download-id-(.*)\.htm$ download.php?id=$1
```

but when i tried to rewrite download.php?id=xx to download.php/id/xx by the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule download/id/(.*)/ download.php?id=$1
RewriteRule download/id/(.*) download.php?id=$1
```

i got an 404 - Not found! error

---

what's the problem
i used this good tool to generate the syntax
http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

Comment: Uh, are you sure that your second rewrite description is accurate?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/id/([0-9]+)\/?$ download.php?id=$1
```

the /? means it can have a trailing slash or not, and the ^ and $ start and end the search string.

Comment: Can you please clarify - what url are you putting in the address bar? For file id 2 It should be /download/id/2/ which would actually serve download.php?id=2 but the address bar would always show the first.